# Does fourier_series only work if the function is symmetrical along the y axis?

Tags: python, sympy, continuous-fourier

Good morning,

I am trying to create a fourier series of a triangular wave through sympy.

The period is from 0 to 1, with f=0 in x=0 and f=1 in x=1. The code is below.

However, it seems as if fourier_series automatically assumes that f=0 in the middle of the interval, at x=0.5. So it assumes that x=0->f=-0.5 and x=1->f=0.5, even though that is not the function I have defined

Could anybody explain me what the problem is?

Thanks

```
from sympy import fourier_series, pi
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x
f = x
s = fourier_series(f, (x, 0, 1))
s1 = s.truncate(n=5)
p = plot(f, s1,  (x, 0, 1), show=False, legend=True)
p.show()
```

Comment: What version of sympy are you using? It looks fine to me with sympy 1.8.

Comment: Cheers, that was the problem. I was running sympy 1.5.1 and was throwing me stupid outputs. I upgraded to sympy 1.8 and works fine